# change the order of lim and sup

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

There is a sequence of nonnegative real valued functions $\{f_n(t)\}$ which  are bounded $|f_n(t)|\le 1 ,\forall n \forall t\in[0,1]$
and $\forall n$
$$\lim_{t\to 0}f_n(t)=0\tag{1}$$
Could we get $$\lim_{t\to 0}\sup_nf_n(t)=0\tag{2}$$
by someting like dominated convergence theorem?

Or the condition (1) is not enough,we have to add $$\text{the convergence in (1) is uniform for n}\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $n$ be an positive integer $>3$.

Define the function $f_n(t)$ as following. Draw the point $(\frac{1}{n},1)$. Then connect a straight line from $(\frac{1}{2n},0)$ up to that point, and from that point connect back down a straight line to $( \frac{2}{n},0)$. Your function should look essentially flat with value $0$, and a short triangular spike at $t=1/n$. Then $f_n \to 0$ pointwise but not uniformly.

Comment: You misunderstand what I mean.(1) and (3) are not equivalent indeed.and (3) implies (2),my question is "Does (1) implies (2)",I want a proof or a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modifying the example from here [Interchanging limit and supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420542/interchanging-limit-and-supremum)

let $f_k(x) = 1 - \left( \frac {1}{1+x}\right)^k\in [0,1], \quad x\in [0,1], k\geq 0$

Then we get $\lim_{x\to 0}f_k(x)= 0$ but $\sup_{k\geq 0}f_k(x)=1$.

The answer also mentions a monotonicity condition that can help.