# Interchanging limit and supremum

Tags: limits, inequality, supremum-and-infimum, sequence-of-function

Sequence of functions is bounded $f_k(x) \le c\ \forall\ k, \forall\ x \ge 0,\ c \in \mathbb{R}$ and decreasing $\forall\ x \ge 0$. Is it possible to show such inequality $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sup_{k \ge 1} f_k(x) \le \sup_{k \ge 1} \lim_{x \to \infty} f_k(x) \text{ ?}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a counter-example: let $$f_k(x) = 1 - \left( \frac {x}{1+x}\right)^k, \quad x\ge 0$$

Then:

- since $g : [0,\infty) \to [0,1) : x \mapsto \frac {x}{1+x}$ is increasing, and $h : [0,1) \to [0,1) : x \mapsto x^k$ is also increasing, so is their composition $h\circ g$. Therefore $f_k : [0,\infty) \to (0,1] : x \mapsto 1 - h\circ g(x)$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$.
- For all $k, \lim_{x \to \infty} f_k(x) = 0$, so $\sup_k \lim_{x \to \infty} f_k(x) = 0$.
- For all $x, \sup_k f_k(x) = 1$, so $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sup_k f_k(x) = 1$.

---

**Original post** (where I thought the sequence was decreasing, not the functions):

If the sequence of functions is decreasing, then for all $k, x, f_1(x) \ge f_k(x)$. Therefore $\sup_{k \ge 1} f_k(x) = f_1(x)$. And $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f_1(x) \ge \lim_{x\to\infty} f_k(x)$$ when they converge (or diverge to $\pm\infty$). So again $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f_1(x) \ge \sup_{k \ge 1} \lim_{x\to\infty} f_k(x)$$
But since the LHS is also one of the values the supremum is being taken over, we must have 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f_1(x) = \sup_{k \ge 1} \lim_{x\to\infty} f_k(x)$$

Thus 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sup_{k \ge 1} f_k(x) = \sup_{k \ge 1} \lim_{x\to\infty} f_k(x)$$

Being bounded below by a constant is not necessary, but convergence of the limits is.

Comment: I asked the question which is probably not correct. I wanted to say that functions are bounded for each k, x and decreasing for each x, but not necessarily for each k.

Comment: The way you phrased it, "decreasing" applies to "sequence", not to "functions". What you should have said is "A sequence of decreasing functions". Then "decreasing" describes the functions and not the sequence. However, since English is not your native language, the mistake is understandable. With the correction, the answer is no, your hypothesis is false. I'll edit my response with a counter-example.